# how to pass a variable to different if statement

Tags: perl

I'm really confused about how to pass a variable into different statement. My code is:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

say "Please enter the first sequence:";
my $sequence1 = <STDIN>;
$sequence1 = chomp $sequence1;
say "Please enter the second sequence:";
my $sequence2 = <STDIN>;
$sequence2 = chomp $sequence2;

if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2){
        my $sequence2_new = substr $sequence2, length $sequence1;
}

my @sequence1 = split(',', $sequence1);
my @sequence2 = split(',', $sequence2_new);
my $element = scalar @sequence1;

my $num = 0;
for ($a = 0; $a < $element; $a++){
        if ($sequence1[$a] = $sequence2[$a]){
                $num++;
        }
}

my $score = $num % length $sequence2;
say "The alignment score is: $score";
```

In this case, this program will return a `Global symbol "$sequence2_new" requires explicit package name at alignment_sequence.pl line 19.`mistake. If I move the "my" declaration in front of if statement in line 14 like `my $sequence2_new;` it will give me `Use of uninitialized value $sequence2_new in split at alignment_sequence.pl line 20, <STDIN> line 2.` warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `my $sequence2_new` *outside* the `if` statement. As you have it, the variable's life ends at the close of the `if` block

Note also that

```
$sequence1 = chomp $sequence1
```

is wrong. It will set `$sequence1` to the number of characters that `chomp` removed—probably 1 or 0. You want just

```
chomp $sequence1
```

You also have `if ( $sequence1[$a] = $sequence2[$a] ) { ... }` which is an *assignment*. Presumably you want the comparator `eq` here?

Here's how I think your code should look, but I'm not at all sure about chopping off the beginning of `$sequence2` if it is longer than `$sequence1`; that doesn't seem at all right, but I have no way of knowing for sure

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

print "Please enter the first sequence: ";
chomp ( my $sequence1 = <> );

print "Please enter the second sequence: ";
chomp ( my $sequence2 = <> );

my $sequence2_new;
if ( length $sequence1 < length $sequence2 ) {
    $sequence2_new = substr $sequence2, length $sequence1;
}

my @sequence1 = split /,/, $sequence1;
my @sequence2 = split /,/, $sequence2_new;

my $num = 0;

for my $a ( 0 .. $#sequence1 ) {

    ++$num if $sequence1[$a] eq $sequence2[$a];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't what is different between your answer and my attempt but it seems working now.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai: I thought I had explained that the declaration of `$sequence2_new` needs to be *outside* the `if`  block for it to survive outside that block. This is a core idea that you must understand as part of most computer languages.

Comment: That's exactly what I did first. So I don't understand why I had a warning at first time but now it's working.

Comment: I found the problem. It seems that I didn't chop correctly.

Comment: @WenjiaZhai: I wrote about that as well. I really don't understand what's tripping you up. There's another problem in that `$sequence2_new` will remain `undef` unless `$sequence1` is shorter than `$sequence2`, but I don't know what your code is supposed to be doing so I couldn't fix it. It will create a warning `Use of uninitialized value in split`.

Comment: It's a homework and I missed something. I need to rewrite the code completely.