# error of "Use of uninitialized value"

Tags: perl

previously I asked about a problem regarding my homework to calculate the alignment score of two protein sequences:
[how to pass a variable to different if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877801/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-different-if-statement)
However, I missed a significant amount of information in the question so I have to rewrite the code.

Now my code is done, but I have a warning as `Use of uninitialized value $sequence2_new in split at alignment_sequence.pl line 52.` Following this warning, there are numerous warning as `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at alignment_sequence.pl line 56.`I understand it because I have an uninitialized value, but I can't understand how it is uninitialized. My code is following:

```
#!/usr/in/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $infile1 = "cystic_fibrosis.fasta";
my $inFH1;
unless (open($inFH1, "<", $infile1)){
    die join (' ', "Can't open", $infile1, $!)
}
my @seq = <$inFH1>;
close $inFH1;
shift @seq;
my $sequence1 = join("", @seq);
$sequence1 =~ s/\n//g;
#parse the query sequence

my $infile2 = "sequence_collection.fasta";
my $inFH2;
unless (open($inFH2, "<", $infile2)){
    die join (' ', "Can't open", $infile2, $!)
}
my $beginning = 1;
my @sequence2;
my $sequence2 = "";
while (my $line = <$inFH2>){
    chomp $line;
    my $chr = substr($line, 0, 1);
    if ($chr ne ">"){
        $sequence2 = $sequence2.$line;
    }else {
        if (! $beginning){
            push @sequence2, $sequence2;
            $sequence2 = "";
        }elsif ($beginning){
            $beginning = 0;
        }
    }
}
close $inFH2;
#parse multiple sequence

my $element = scalar(@sequence2);
for ($a = 0; $a < $element; $a++ ){
    my $sequence2_new;
    if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]){
        $sequence2_new = substr ($sequence2[$a], 0, length $sequence1);
    }

    my @sequence1_new = split('', $sequence1);
    my @sequence2_new = split('', $sequence2_new);
    my $element_new = scalar(@sequence1_new);

    my $num = 0;
    for ($b = 0; $b < $element_new; $b++){
        if ($sequence1_new[$b] eq $sequence2_new[$b]){
            $num++;
        }
    }

    my $score = $num / length $sequence1;
    say $sequence1;
    say $sequence2[$a];
    say "\n";
    print "The alignment score is: ";
    printf("%.2f", $score);
    say "\n\n";
}
```

The file `cystic_fibrosis.fasta` contains:

```
>gi|90421313|ref|NP_000483.3| cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator [Homo sapiens]
MQRSPLEKASVVSKLFFSWTRPILRKGYRQRLELSDIYQIPSVDSADNLSEKLEREWDRELASKKNPKLI
NALRRCFFWRFMFYGIFLYLGEVTKAVQPLLLGRIIASYDPDNKEERSIAIYLGIGLCLLFIVRTLLLHP
AIFGLHHIGMQMRIAMFSLIYKKTLKLSSRVLDKISIGQLVSLLSNNLNKFDEGLALAHFVWIAPLQVAL
LMGLIWELLQASAFCGLGFLIVLALFQAGLGRMMMKYRDQRAGKISERLVITSEMIENIQSVKAYCWEEA
MEKMIENLRQTELKLTRKAAYVRYFNSSAFFFSGFFVVFLSVLPYALIKGIILRKIFTTISFCIVLRMAV
TRQFPWAVQTWYDSLGAINKIQDFLQKQEYKTLEYNLTTTEVVMENVTAFWEEGFGELFEKAKQNNNNRK
TSNGDDSLFFSNFSLLGTPVLKDINFKIERGQLLAVAGSTGAGKTSLLMVIMGELEPSEGKIKHSGRISF
CSQFSWIMPGTIKENIIFGVSYDEYRYRSVIKACQLEEDISKFAEKDNIVLGEGGITLSGGQRARISLAR
AVYKDADLYLLDSPFGYLDVLTEKEIFESCVCKLMANKTRILVTSKMEHLKKADKILILHEGSSYFYGTF
SELQNLQPDFSSKLMGCDSFDQFSAERRNSILTETLHRFSLEGDAPVSWTETKKQSFKQTGEFGEKRKNS
ILNPINSIRKFSIVQKTPLQMNGIEEDSDEPLERRLSLVPDSEQGEAILPRISVISTGPTLQARRRQSVL
NLMTHSVNQGQNIHRKTTASTRKVSLAPQANLTELDIYSRRLSQETGLEISEEINEEDLKECFFDDMESI
PAVTTWNTYLRYITVHKSLIFVLIWCLVIFLAEVAASLVVLWLLGNTPLQDKGNSTHSRNNSYAVIITST
SSYYVFYIYVGVADTLLAMGFFRGLPLVHTLITVSKILHHKMLHSVLQAPMSTLNTLKAGGILNRFSKDI
AILDDLLPLTIFDFIQLLLIVIGAIAVVAVLQPYIFVATVPVIVAFIMLRAYFLQTSQQLKQLESEGRSP
IFTHLVTSLKGLWTLRAFGRQPYFETLFHKALNLHTANWFLYLSTLRWFQMRIEMIFVIFFIAVTFISIL
TTGEGEGRVGIILTLAMNIMSTLQWAVNSSIDVDSLMRSVSRVFKFIDMPTEGKPTKSTKPYKNGQLSKV
MIIENSHVKKDDIWPSGGQMTVKDLTAKYTEGGNAILENISFSISPGQRVGLLGRTGSGKSTLLSAFLRL
LNTEGEIQIDGVSWDSITLQQWRKAFGVIPQKVFIFSGTFRKNLDPYEQWSDQEIWKVADEVGLRSVIEQ
FPGKLDFVLVDGGCVLSHGHKQLMCLARSVLSKAKILLLDEPSAHLDPVTYQIIRRTLKQAFADCTVILC
EHRIEAMLECQQFLVIEENKVRQYDSIQKLLNERSLFRQAISPSDRVKLFPHRNSSKCKSKPQIAALKEE
TEEEVQDTRL
```

The file `sequence_collection.fasta` contains 100 similar blocks:

```
>gi|1100985|gb|AAC48608.1| CFTR chloride channel [Oryctolagus cuniculus]
MQRSPLEKAGVLSKLFFSWTRPILRKGYRQRLELSDIYQIPSADSADNLSEKLEREWDRELASKKNPKLI
NALRRCFFWRFMFYGIFLYLGEVTKAVQPLLLGRIIASYDPDNKEERSIAIYLGIGLCLLFVVRTLLLHP
AIFGLHHIGMQMRIAMFSLIYKKGLALAHFVWISPLQVTLLMGLLWELLQASAFCGLAFLIVLALVQAGL
GRMMMKYRDQRAGKINERLVITSEMIENIQSVKAYCWEEAMEKMIENLRQTELKLTRKAAYVRYFNSSAF
FFSGFFVVFLSVLPYALTKGIILRKIFTTISFCIVLRMAVTRQFPWAVQTWYDSLGAINKIQDFLQKQEY
KTLEYNLTTTEVVMDNVTAFWEEGFGELFEKAKQNNSDRKISNGDNNLFFSNFSLLGAPVLEDISFKIER
GQLLAVAGSTGAGKTSLLMMITGELEPSEGKIKHSGRISFCSQFSWIMPGTIKENIIFGVSYDEYRYRSV
IKACQLEEDISKFTEKDNTVLGEGGITLSGGQRARISLARAVYKDADLYLLDSPFGYLDVLTEKEIFESC
VCKLMANKTRIMVTSKMEHLKKADKILILHEGSSYFYGTFSELQSLRPDFSSKLMGYDSFDQFSAERRNS
ILTETLRRFSLEGDASVSWNDTRKQSFKQNGELGEKRKNSILNPVNSMRKFSIVLKTPLQMNGIEEDSDA
TIERRLSLVPDSEQGEAILPRSNMINTGPMLQGCRRQSVLNLMTHSVSQGPSIYRRTTTSTRKMSLAPQT
NLTEMDIYSRRLSQESGLEISEEINEEDLKECFIDDVDSIPTVTTWNTYLRYITVHRSLIFVLIWCIVIF
LAEVAASLVVLWLFGNTAPQDKENSTKSGNSSYAVIITNTSSYYFFYIYVGVADTLLALGLFRGLPLVHT
LITVSKILHHKMLHSVLQAPMSTLNTLKAGGILNRFSKDIAILDDLLPLTIFDFIQLLLIVVGAIAVVSV
LQPYIFLATVPVIAAFILLRAYFLHTSQQLKQLESEGRSPIFTHLVTSLKGLWTLRAFGRQPYFETLFHK
ALNLHTANWFLYLSTLRWFQMRIEMIFVLFFIAVAFISILTTGEGEGRVGIILTLAMNIMSTLQWAVNSS
IDVDSLMQSVSRVFMFIDMPTEAKSTKSIKPSSNCQLSKVMIIENQHVKKDDVWPSGGQMTVKGLTAKYI
DSGNAILENISFSISPGQRVGLLGRTGSGKSTLLSAFLRLLSTEGEIQIDGVSWDSITLQQWRKAFGVIP
QKVFIFSGTFRKNLDPYEQWSDQEIWKVADEVGLRSVIEQFPGKLDFVLVDGGYVLSHGHKQLMCLARSV
LSKAKILLLDEPSAHLDPITYQIIRRTLKQAFADCTVILCEHRIEAMLECQRFLVIEENTVRQYESIQKL
LSEKSLFRQAISSSDRAKLFPHRNSSKHKSRPQITALKEEAEEEVQGTRL
```

Sorry I know it's very redundant. I will greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Uninitialized actually means undefined (through lack of initialization or otherwise)

Comment: What happens if the condition in `if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]) { ... }` is false...

Comment: I know that, but I think I define it.

Comment: You never assign anything to it, so it's undefined.

Comment: That's exactly my question. I define `$sequence2_new` by `$sequence2_new = substr ($sequence2[$a], 0, length $sequence1);` but perl still tells me it's undefined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: No, you don't execute that when `length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]` is false. I ask again: What happens when `length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]` is false?

Comment: That's a good point, so I rewrite this part of code:`if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]){
  $sequence2_new = substr ($sequence2[$a], 0, length $sequence1);
  $sequence1_new = $sequence1;
 }elsif (length $sequence1 > length $sequence2[$a]){
  $sequence1_new = substr($sequence1, 0, length $sequence2[$a]);
  $sequence2_new = $sequence2[$a];
 }`However the problem still exists.

Comment: Of course it does. You still use `$sequence2_new` without assigning anything to it when `length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]` is false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157250/discussion-between-wenjia-zhai-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code, you do not assign a value to `$sequence2_new` when the `if` condition is false. That means it remains `undef`.

```
my $sequence2_new;
if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]){
    $sequence2_new = substr ($sequence2[$a], 0, length $sequence1);
}
```

Try assigning a value to it:

```
my $sequence2_new = '';
if (length $sequence1 < length $sequence2[$a]){
    $sequence2_new = substr ($sequence2[$a], 0, length $sequence1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly the problem.